# How can I instantiate and programmatically register beans to Spring ApplicationContext from a test class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I attempting to instantiate Spring boot applicationContext and dynamically register beans within a test class to so it can acts as the real main class client's behavior. But I run the code (sample below) somehow the bean I register gets lost when it reaches to `ClassFromMainCode.isBean` method.

##### Testing class

```java
@SpringBootTest( 
   classes = { ClassFromMainCode.class },
   webEnvironment = Spring.WebEnvironment.NONE
)
@Configuration
@ContextConfiguration
public class SampleTestClass {
  private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;  

  @Test
  public void testCase1() {
          beanName = "abc";
          Class beanClass = String.class;
          registerSpringBean(beanName, beanClass);

          //returns False
          new ClassFromMainCode().isBean(beanName);

          //returns True
          this.applicationContext.containsBean(beanName);
  }  

  private void registerSpringBean(String beanName, Class<?> beanClass) {
          BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) applicationContext;
          registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, new TestGenericBeanDefinition(beanClass));
          applicationContext.refresh();
  }  

  public SampleTestClass() {
          applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
  }
}
```

##### Main class

```java
@Component
public class ClassFromMainCode {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  boolean isBean(String beanName) {
          return applicationContext.containsBean(beanName);
  }
}
```

I expected the `new ClassFromMainCode().isBean(beanName);` to return true instead of false. I am wondering how I can appropriately define Spring applicationContext and register beans in a way that is presevered to reach to main code?

Answer (score 0):

You are having two different application contexts. (1) created by you in the constructor of the test class. You use this one in your test method to register a bean called "abc". (2) created by Spring as a result of your annotation `@SpringBootTest` on your test class. This context only contains beans declared in the classes specified in the `classes` property. You have only one class declared in that property `ClassFromMainCode` which doesn't contain any beans.

> I expected the new ClassFromMainCode().isBean(beanName); to return
> true instead of false. I am wondering how I can appropriately define
> Spring applicationContext and register beans in a way that is
> presevered to reach to main code?

**Fix**

Instead of creating your own application context in the constructor, use the one created by Spring for you. Autowire it in your test class and use that one instead.

```
@SpringBootTest( 
   classes = { ClassFromMainCode.class },
   webEnvironment = Spring.WebEnvironment.NONE
)
@Configuration
@ContextConfiguration
public class SampleTestClass {

   @Autowired
   private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;
   ...
   ...
}
```

Delete the constructor.